# Can I set terraform output to env variables?

Tags: bash, terminal, terraform, hashicorp-vault

So terraform generates a bunch of the output I'm interested in. How can pipe those values to environment variables or something such that my script will be able to pick them up after someone runs `terraform apply`?

Answer (score 27):

Terraform can't directly modify the environment of the shell that called it --generally, a program can only modify its own environment or set a new environment when starting a child program itself -- so any solution here will involve taking additional action in the calling shell once `terraform apply` returns.

One way you could do this is to pipe the output from `terraform output -json` into a program that can parse the JSON, extract the relevant values, and then print them out as one or more shell statements to set environment variables. You could then run the result of that program as a shell script, for example using the `source` command in bash, to incorporate those environment variable values into your current shell.

You could write this transforming program in any programming language you are comfortable with. For simple cases you might like to write a simple shell script using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), relying on its `@sh` escaping mode to guarantee valid shell quoting of the values:

```
terraform output -json | jq -r '@sh "export EXAMPLE1=\(.example1.value)\nexport EXAMPLE2=\(.example2.value)"'
```

I tried this with the following test Terraform configuration:

```
output "example1" {
  value = "hello"
}

output "example2" {
  value = <<EOT
Hello world
This is a multi-line string with 'quotes' in "it".
EOT
}
```

After applying that configuration, the command above produced the following output:

```
export EXAMPLE1='hello'
export EXAMPLE2='Hello world
This is a multi-line string with '\''quotes'\'' in "it".
'
```

I redirected the output to a file `env.sh` and then loaded it into my shell to confirm that the variables were usable:

```
$ terraform output -json | jq -r '@sh "export EXAMPLE1=\(.example1.value)\nexport EXAMPLE2=\(.example2.value)"' >env.sh
$ source env.sh 
$ echo $EXAMPLE1
hello
$ echo "$EXAMPLE2"
Hello world
This is a multi-line string with 'quotes' in "it".
```

(Note that for `EXAMPLE2` I put the variable interpolation in quotes, because otherwise the shell will understand each of the space-separated words as a separate argument, rather than considering the whole value as a single string with all of the whitespace characters intact.)

Comment: What a great answer.

Answer (score 17):

as stated before, you can't take the value from `terraform apply`, you can use `terraform output`.

I would also suggest to use `-raw`, from help

```
  -raw             For value types that can be automatically
                   converted to a string, will print the raw
                   string directly, rather than a human-oriented
                   representation of the value.
```

Example how I use:

`KMS_KEY_ID=$(terraform output -raw kms_secrets_id)`

I hope it helps somebody

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was always piping it through sed to strip the quotes. I did not know about the `-raw` flag until now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I was also puzzled why nobody wrote anything about `-raw`, i guess it's new terraform feature!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to export the output of the terraform to environment variables.

```
export $(terraform output | sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' | xargs)
```

The middle part of the command, `sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g'` is responsible for removing the space between the equal (`=`) sign.
It will convert from  `KEY = "VALUE"` to `KEY="VALUE"`. The last part, `xargs` will convert `KEY="VALUE"` to `KEY=VALUE` which is the standard way of exporting values into environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

After doing entirely too much digging, I found a solution that will work on my Mac (as well as any other system with jq afaik).

This will export ALL Terraform outputs. This is an expansion upon @martin-atkins answer (thanks!):

Here's an example outputs.tf file to try it out on:

```
output "first_service_port" {
  description = "The port that ECS service first is on"
  value       = 8080
}

output "second_service_port" {
  description = "The port that ECS service second is on"
  value       = 8081
}
```

Once you've run `terraform apply` you can then run:

```
terraform output -json | jq -r 'to_entries[] | .key + "=" + (.value.value | tostring)' | while read -r line ; do echo export "$line"; done > env.sh
source env.sh
```

The proof:

```
$ echo $first_service_port
8080
$ echo $second_service_port
8081
```